# Ошибка при передаче массива в другое активити

Tags: java, android, массивы, android-intent

Есть одномерный массив

```
String [] mas=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mas);
```

Его нужно  при клике по  button_3 передать в другое активити:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent3 = new Intent(this,Test_3.class);
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button_3:

                 intent3.putExtra("mas",mas);
                 startActivity(intent3);
                break;
```

В другом активити переданный массив получается так:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String[] mas3 = extras.getStringArray("mas");
```

Затем первый элемент массива отображается в текстовом поле:

```
int counter = 0;
  textView.setText(mas3[counter]);
```

В итоге после клика по кнопке переход на другое активити не осуществляется, выдает ошибку, ссылаясь на последнюю строку

```
 textView.setText(mas3[counter]);
```

Подскажите, в чем ошибка?

Comment: Ошибка то какая?

Comment: Могу предложить информацию массива передать через Intent.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего вы ищите свой массив не там. Попробуйте его искать прямо в интенте, а не в его `Bundle`

```
String[] mas3 = getIntent().getStringArray("mas");
```

Либо тогда уж помещать сначала массив в `Bundle`, `Bundle` в `Intent` и вытаскивать так, как вы сейчас вытаскиваете:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArray("mas",mas);
intent3.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent3);
```

А ошибка возникает, видимо, из-за того, что при ненахождении значения в `Bundle` по умолчанию подставляется `null`

Comment: А если через интент на второе активити могут быть переданы разные массивы, то как понять какой передан? Какое значение по умолчанию можно поставить вместе с ключом?

Comment: Есть метод `contains(String key)`, возвращающий есть или нет значение с переданным в него ключом в `Bundle`. А значение по умолчанию вы можете поставить любое подходящее вторым аргументом методов `get...(String key, SOME_CLASS defaultValue)`

Comment: все получилось, спасибо, только не contains(String key), а containsKey(String key)