# Не могу извлечь данные из putExtra&

Tags: android, listview, activity, android-intent

Есть 2 Activity, хочу из первого Activity listView через intent передать во 2 Activity данные реализовал таким методом:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, about.class);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
            intent.putExtra("key1", getResource().getString(R.string.tekst1));
            break;
            case 1:
            intent.putExtra("ke2", getResource().getString(R.string.tekst2));
            break ;
            case 2:
            intent.putExtra("key3", getResource ().getString(R.string.tekst3));
            break ;
        }
        startActivity (intent) ;
    }
});
```

А вот так пытался во втором активити извлечь:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findbyiD(R.id.textview);
String tekst =getIntent().getExtras().getString("key1");
switch(i){
case 0:
TextView.setText(key1)
case1:
break;

textview.setText(key2)
case2:
break;

texView.setTex(key3)
break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String text = extras.getString("key1");
```

или так:

```
switch(i) {
    case 0:
        TextView.setText(extras.getString("key1"))
        break;
    case1:
        textview.setText(extras.getString("key2"))
        break;
    case2:
        texView.setTex(extras.getString("key3"))
        break;
}
```

Comment: switch i загарается красным

Comment: ну это вы сами решаете чем является `i`. Я предполагаю что это `position` в методе `onItemClick` в первом Activity. Если да то можете передать через intent и его значение. А потом приравнять это значение переменной `i`

Comment: Да это именно position а как и его передать через intent &&&????буду очень блогадарен

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вопрос аналогичен [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/502897/17609)

Вы ищете не там ваш extras. Вы его поместили прямо в Intent, а ищете во внутреннем Bundle Intent-a.

Т.е. вам надо как-то так вытаскивать:

```
String tekst = getIntent().getStringExtra("key1", "error");
```

Comment: не получилось сноа( чтото яно не так

Comment: я скорее немогу найти case  по position ошибка где swtich

Comment: @elik, ну, у вас там, во второй активити какая-то путаница с break

Comment: прошу помоч п точнее сперва покажите как извлечь ut extra  а потом помогите с условием для кнопки какая была нажата